# Recommendations for library/plugin/app to allow the user to customize/personalize item by adding text/colors/img etc.?

Tags: plugins, web-applications, e-commerce, integration, bigcommerce

I'm trying to figure out a way to integrate the option for users to make their own style/design of a product by adding their image/text/logo etc. Any recommendations ? It's specifically for an e-commerce (BigCommerce) website.

Comment: *"Recommendations for library/plugin/app"* are explicitly off topic here per the [help].

Comment: Hey Samuil, are you looking for an app like this? https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/product-customizer-by-inkybay/ Or is the use case a bit different?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, once again thank you, Karen! I was wondering if I can create something similar, but it will take huge amount of time probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hey Samuil, are you looking for an app like this? bigcommerce.com/apps/product-customizer-by-inkybay Or is the use case a bit different? – Karen White "

Thank you, Karen!